# Spark - Add a column which sums another column, grouped by a third column, without losing other columns

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with 5 columns:
`col11`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4` and `col5`

I'd like to add `col6` which would be the sum of `col5`, grouped by `col1`. But I don't want to lose the other columns.

If I do:

```scala
df
  .groupBy("col1")
  .agg(sum("col5") as "col6")
```

Then I lose columns 2-4.

I can do a join by running:

```scala
val sumValues = df
  .groupBy("col1")
  .agg(sum("col5") as "col6")

df
  .join(sumValues, Seq("col1"))
```

But it feels an over-kill.

I was hoping to do something like:

```scala
df
  .withGroupedColumn("col6", "col1", sum("col5") as "col6")
```

Is there a simple way to do that in Spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("col6", expr("sum(col5) over (partition by col1)"))
```

Or equivalently

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df2 = df.withColumn("col6", sum("col5").over(Window.partitionBy("col1")))
```